# How define some constraints in python using pulp

Tags: python, pulp

I'm trying to implement an optimization code using pulp in python.

This is the first time that I do a model using this language.

And I'm with some problems.

Consider the optimization model:

[image]

n_i_t - is an input of data with dimensions I and T. Is a matrix of floats data.
lambe_i_t - is an input of data with dimensions I and T. Is a matrix of floats data.
C - is an int input of data
a_i_t - is an decision variable

My code is like this:

```
#Initialize model
model = LpProblem('eUCB_Model', sense=LpMaximize)
#Define decision variables
    
#y = LpVariable.dicts('tenant', [(i) for i in range(I) for t in range (T)], lowBound=None, upBound=None, cat='Binary')

#Define model
model += lpSum([y[t][i]*n[t][i] for i in range(I) for t in range(T)])
        
#Define Constraints
model += lpSum([y[t][i]*R[t][i] for i in range(I) for t in range(T)]) <= C

model.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))
```

There is two problems here:

1. I can't define the restriction 3 - lookup. This restriction will guarantee that once time the variable a is 1, the variable needs to be 1 for a period of time, for exemple, during 5 units of T.
2. My variable a not returns when the variable is 1 and when is 0. In CPLEX I have all this information, but here, I don't know how define this informations.

Can someone help me to correct this code?

thank you very much

Comment: What do your lock-up constraints look like in CPLEX? - I don't fully follow the notation of your problem formulation.